unable to find file in Dockerfile but it is there. exec /usr/local/bin/script.sh: no such file or directory
I have a dockerfile that is giving me an error that reads
exec /usr/local/bin/script.sh: no such file or directory
The file is most definitely there. I have the #!/bin/zsh on top of the script and when I change it to #!/usr/bin/env bash I get an error that reads env: can't execute 'bash': No such file or directory. There are no hidden characters cat -e script.sh and the file is executable.
script
#!/bin/zsh

#API_URL="http://$API_HOST:$API_PORT/v1/healthcheck"
API_URL="http://localhost:8081/v1/healthcheck"
echo "Calling URL: $API_URL"

for i in {1..25}; do
  curl -s "$API_URL"
  #curl -s -o /dev/null -w "Response: %{http_code}\n" "$API_URL"
done

Dockerfile
FROM alpine/curl

COPY script.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/script.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/script.sh"]

I am trying to debug a connection issue on GCP Cloud Run but I cannot get it to work locally. I am not sure why it will not execute the file when it can find it but says it cannot.

There is no bash or zsh in this image:
$ docker run --rm --entrypoint=sh -it alpine/curl
/ # type bash
bash: not found
/ # type zsh
zsh: not found

There is /bin/sh which is a symlink to busybox:
/ # type sh
sh is /bin/sh
/ # ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Sep  6 11:34 /bin/sh -> /bin/busybox

So you need to change shebang in your script to:
#!/bin/sh

and don't use bash and zsh specific features so it should be:
#!/bin/sh

#API_URL="http://$API_HOST:$API_PORT/v1/healthcheck"
API_URL="http://localhost:8081/v1/healthcheck"
echo "Calling URL: $API_URL"

for i in $(seq 1 25); do    
  curl -s "$API_URL"
  #curl -s -o /dev/null -w "Response: %{http_code}\n" "$API_URL"
done

